# What are the suitable problems for Akka vs Gridgain? When is one more suitable than the other?

Tags: scala, akka, gridgain

I am trying to understand the differences between Akka and Gridgain. Please explain when one is more suitable than the other and for what problems?

http://akka.io/

http://www.gridgain.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Akka` implements the `Actor Framework` in Scala/Java.

The main use case of using Akka is when you need a **massively** concurrent application.

Think telecom applications where you need to route messages. In fact Akka finds its inspiration from Ericsson's Erlang.

Here are some more use cases from the Akka site : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/intro/use-cases.html

`GridGain` appears to be a data processing framework using Map Reduce concepts internally.

Think Big Data here. To process insanely large data sets you need better processing frameworks.

Disclaimer : I haven't used GridGain.